# Java performance exercise: 0%

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I made this test to challenge myself while learning a bit of Java, and I got the worst possible result in the performance test, 0%.

This was the exercise:

> You are given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of
>   N integers. These arrays represent N planks. More precisely, A[K] is
>   the start and B[K] the end of the K−th plank.
>
> Next, you are given a non-empty zero-indexed array C consisting of M
>   integers. This array represents M nails. More precisely, C[I] is the
>   position where you can hammer in the I−th nail.
>
> We say that a plank (A[K], B[K]) is nailed if there exists a nail C[I]
>   such that A[K] ≤ C[I] ≤ B[K].
>
> The goal is to find the minimum number of nails that must be used
>   until all the planks are nailed. In other words, you should find a
>   value J such that all planks will be nailed after using only the first
>   J nails. More precisely, for every plank (A[K], B[K]) such that 0 ≤ K
>   < N, there should exist a nail C[I] such that I < J and A[K] ≤ C[I] ≤
>   B[K].
>
> For example, given arrays A, B such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 1    B[0] = 4
> A[1] = 4    B[1] = 5
> A[2] = 5    B[2] = 9
> A[3] = 8    B[3] = 10 four planks are represented: [1, 4], [4, 5], [5, 9] and [8, 10].
> ```
>
> Given array C such that:
>
> ```
> C[0] = 4
> C[1] = 6
> C[2] = 7
> C[3] = 10
> C[4] = 2 if we use the following nails:
> ```
>
> 0, then planks [1, 4] and [4, 5] will both be nailed. 0, 1, then
>   planks [1, 4], [4, 5] and [5, 9] will be nailed. 0, 1, 2, then planks
>   [1, 4], [4, 5] and [5, 9] will be nailed. 0, 1, 2, 3, then all the
>   planks will be nailed. Thus, four is the minimum number of nails that,
>   used sequentially, allow all the planks to be nailed.
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C); }
>
> that, given two non-empty zero-indexed arrays A and B consisting of N
>   integers and a non-empty zero-indexed array C consisting of M
>   integers, returns the minimum number of nails that, used sequentially,
>   allow all the planks to be nailed.
>
> If it is not possible to nail all the planks, the function should
>   return −1.
>
> For example, given arrays A, B, C such that:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 1    B[0] = 4
> A[1] = 4    B[1] = 5
> A[2] = 5    B[2] = 9
> A[3] = 8    B[3] = 10
>
> C[0] = 4
> C[1] = 6
> C[2] = 7
> C[3] = 10
> C[4] = 2 the function should return 4, as explained above.
> ```
>
> Assume that:
>
> N and M are integers within the range [1..30,000]; each element of
>   arrays A, B, C is an integer within the range [1..2*M]; A[K] ≤ B[K].
>   Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O((N+M)*log(M)); expected
>   worst-case space complexity is O(M), beyond input storage (not
>   counting the storage required for input arguments). Elements of input
>   arrays can be modified.

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {

        int result = 0;
        int empties = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < C.length; i ++){

            for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j ++){

                if(A[j] != 0){

                    if(C[i] >= A[j] && C[i] <= B[j]){

                        A[j] = B[j] = 0;
                        empties ++;

                    }
                }

                if(empties == A.length){

                    return i + 1;

                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

This is the link of the result: https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingXXEXMW-KVJ/

Questions:

**First**, I don't understand why my performance is measured O((N + M) * N) and not O(M * N), since I'm doing a for (M) and inside a for(N). Disclaimer, I only learned about Big O notation a couple of days ago.

**Second**, most likely the reason why the performance was bad was because I didn't use a binary search to find the nail-able elements, instead I looped through them.

However, I did that on purpose since in no part of the exercise is mentioned that the A and B arrays are sorted, in a way that 1 >= A[K] >= A[K+1]. And if I sorted those arrays, then the performance would be bad (I guess, no idea how much the sort hurts the performance honestly, just a guesstimate).

What is your opinion about it?.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add my solution, ty for the edit.

Comment: I run your code with C as `{4,6,2,7,10}`, A and B are the one given in the exemple. As matching nails are not consecutive, it should return `-1`. I got `5`. Your code is wrong so you got 0%.

Comment: @jhamon The correcness tests of the site seem to pass (they may not cover all cases, though....).

Comment: well, using a sorted C array (`{2,4,6,7,10}`) also return `5`... You passed the test with the exemple values, but maybe the performance test runs tests with other values

Comment: The "consecutiveness" of the matching nails is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: `minimum number of nails that, used sequentially` I may not have understood that correctly. Anyway, it returns 4 instead of 5.

Comment: Sequentially means that I use nail by nail, and when I find enough to nail every single plank, I'm done. I doubt the algorithm is incorrect in terms of delivering the right result.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why my performance is measured O((N + M) * N) and not O(M * N)

They are probably doing curve fitting against a limited number of curves.  (This is the problem with trying to determine complexity empirically.)

> And if I sorted those arrays, then the performance would be bad (I guess, no idea how much the sort hurts the performance honestly, just a guesstimate).

Actually, sorting will be `O(NlogN)` if done with a good algorithm.  So from a complexity perspective you could achieve the `O(NlogN)` overall worst-case by sorting and then doing a binary search.  (I'm not saying it is the right solution though ....)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I can't sort the arrays, since they come in pairs. Sorting them would destroy the "plank" system.

Comment: Sure you can sort them.  You just need to use something other than `Arrays.sort(...)`.  Or turn the 2 arrays of ints into 1 array of pairs.  But again, I'm not saying that this is the right solution.  I'm just talking about whether you can meet the complexity goal by sorting.